# <a name="whatever"></a> deprecated Batch convert to id

Tags: html, batch-file, replace

I have a lot of old html files that I need to update.  Hopefully, not manually.

I can use a find/replace app to go through a directory and find all with `<a name=` and replace it `<span id=` since "name" is deprecated.  How would I then find all of the correct endtags and convert `</a>` to `</span>` without ruining all hyperlinks?

TIA,
Linda

edit: I am using a Mac.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? "name" is still a legal attribute of an anchor in HTML 4.01: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-name-A. Or are you trying to find anchors that were ID'd using the name attribute?

Comment: Also, just converting all anchors to spans is not reliable. Doing it manually allows for much finer control (and much less pointless span elements, I'd guess).

Comment: >>What are you trying to accomplish? "name" is still a legal attribute of an anchor in HTML 4.01:<< I am moving on to HTML5.  The pages will be used in a UIWebView on the iPhone and iPad.  I realize it is not necessary but with HTML5, the "name" has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This thread from earlier today may be useful, as it contains a discussion of tools for parsing HTML.

[c#: crawler project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884452/c-crawler-project/3884478#3884478)

Here's a specific tool available on MSDN:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SgmlReader

Essentially, there are many options available for manipulating an HTML DOM. These tools would allow you to wrap anchors in spans (if that was the intention), remove unwanted attributes, etc.

EDIT: Per the OP's requirement to use a Mac, ANTLR might get the job done:

http://www.antlr.org/grammar/HTML

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using a Mac.